# Why do I get java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in browser but not in eclipse applet viewer?

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, invocationtargetexception

Just like the title says: Why do I get java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in browser but not in eclipse applet viewer? When I run my applet (yes, i know applets are outdated) in the browser using html to load it, i get the java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException error. I read that this happens when the HTML is trying to load something that is not an applet, but it works when I run it as an applet in eclipse (brings up eclipse java applet viewer and works perfect...that is what stumps me). Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.runOnEDTAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.instantiateApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.OldPluginAWTUtil.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "hq.gif" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImageFromHash(SunToolkit.java:774)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImage(SunToolkit.java:790)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit.getImage(LWCToolkit.java:471)
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:147)
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:174)
    at Application.Game.<init>(Game.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:302)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

My file structure is like this:

```
index.html
java.policy.applet
hq.gif
b.gif
k.gif
Application (this is the package)/
     Game.java
     Game.class
     ETC
```

My java.policy.applet

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Comment: Can you post just the stacktrace?

Comment: @Hirak There we go :)

Comment: The reason is here: `Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "hq.gif" "read")`. Where is this image?

Comment: @StephaneM i added my file structure to the OP. Does it have something to do with calling it (with index.html) from outside the application package folder? Would this be why it works in the java applet viewer but not in the browser with index.html?

Answer (score 2):

```
InvocationtargetException is a generic one. The actual exception is
```

> Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.io.FilePermission" "hq.gif" "read")

What I assume is, you would need admin priviledges while running the applet in addition to the signed jar.

Can you incorporate the following code, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590269/accesscontrolexception-access-denied-filepermission)

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
    public Object run() {
        // perform the security-sensitive operation here
        return null;
    }
});
```